# Windows Charting.Chart Performance

Tags: wpf, windows, performance, charts

I have a System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart in a WPF window.  I am trying to display a line chart with about 150 series that have about 500 points each, the data is static and the chart does not take a particularly long time to render.

The problem is that the window hosting the chart control is fairly unresponsive, i.e. when moving/resizing.

Additionally I am zooming in to a range of 100 points on the x-axis, with a horizontal scroll, and the scroll bar is so slow it is pretty much unusable.

Has anyone else noticed particularly poor performance with this type of chart?

Is there an easy way to implement a kind of lazy loading, that would only draw the points when the part of the chart is scrolled into view?

Thanks.

Comment: 75,000 data points is a lot.  The following blog post states that even 1,000 data points is too much, but you should glance the blog over and see if there are any other performance tips: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/01/13/i-feel-the-need-the-need-for-speed-seven-simple-performance-boosting-tweaks-for-common-silverlight-wpf-charting-scenarios.aspx

Comment: As far as I remember, back when I was testing WPF charting, Charting.Charts didn't have a very good overall performance. I finally switched to Visiblox which is one of the fastest, but as of now, you need to pay for it :(

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, however this seems to be an article on WPF charts and I am using a winforms chart, albeit hosted in a wpf window,  I think from what I have read the winforms charts do perform better.  I have managed to improve slightly by turning off anti-aliasing and using the fast line rather than line type, looks a bit pants now though :(

Comment: Turns out the best performance increase I could get was by turning off the tool tips.  I have a tool tip that eluded to the X value for each point on the chart, once disabled the performance improved a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, no pun intended.